# Updating Less Css

Tags: npm

I had Less Css working on my 12.1 Ubuntu install fine. I was using it by running lessc from command line.

When I run lessc -v I get:

```
lessc 1.3.0 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

I need to upgrade to 1.3.3, after reading a lot on the web I tried the npm install (as I thought that was how I installed initially) "npm install less" this returned:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-1.3.3.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/less/-/less-1.3.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin/-/ycssmin-1.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ycssmin/-/ycssmin-1.0.1.tgz
less@1.3.3 node_modules/less
```

Now however I still get verison 1.3 when running lessc -v.

I think I must have installed originally through apt-get. I am now confused, so to the question.

Is installing through NPM different than apt-get, i.e. a different implementation?

How can I get to a 1.3.3 install?

Many thanks,

Comment: NPM is definitely different from installing via `apt-get`. NPM pulls its files directly from `registry.npmjs.org` whereas `apt-get` pulls pre-packaged `DEB` archives from your local Ubuntu mirror.

Comment: Did you try the nodejs ppa https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/

Comment: I wonder if what I installed via apt-get is overriding the NPM install (when I installed via NPM it said it was installing 1.3.3 but I only get 1.3 from the command line less -v)?

Comment: Hi Luis - thanks for the comment, if I try that PPA do I have to re-install Less somehow?

Comment: Nobody out there know how I might get to Less 1.3.3 ? :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get lessc 1.3.3 I had to

```
 sudo apt-get remove node-less
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
 sudo npm install -g less
```

Otherwise I was also getting version 1.3.0.

I've also had to resort to yui-compressor as uglifyjs doesn't work after this change of libraries.

Comment: Great - thanks, quick question.. when running lessc do you have to run it as sudo? When I run mine without sudo I get an error...